# Error al llamar a dos métodos de una clase

Tags: python, poo, pandas

Me estoy iniciando en POO. Como ejercicio, me he planteado construir una clase que construya lo que, en estadística, se denomina intervalos de clase.

Esta función, simula un registro de ventas.

```
import numpy as np # importando numpy
import pandas as pd # importando pandas
import math
import os

def datos_ventas():
    np.random.seed(0)  # seed for reproducibility

    data = np.random.randint(1, 99, (52, 6))  # 

    pd.set_option('precision', 2)
    # array de una lista.
    lista_ventas = data[:,:].flatten()
    # Lista ordenada de datos
    lista_ordenada = np.sort(lista_ventas, axis=None)
    # df de ventas
    df_ventas = pd.DataFrame(data)
    # Crear un df de una única columna, con una lista
    ventas =  pd.DataFrame(lista_ventas)  
    ventas.columns = (["Valores"])
    return df_ventas, lista_ventas, lista_ordenada, ventas
df_ventas, lista_ventas, lista_ordenada, ventas = datos_ventas()
ventas[:3]
```

La clase que he desarrollado es la siguente

```
class ConstruyeIntervalos:
    def __init(self):
        self.df = df
        
    """Número de muestras"""
    def calcula_numero_muestras(self, df):
        """Número de muestras"""
        self.M = df.size
        return self.M

    """Recorrido de la variable""" 
    def calcula_recorrido (self, df):
        # Variables máxima y mínima
        self.max = df.values.max() 
        self.min = df.values.min()   
        self.R =  (self.max  - self.min ) 
        return self.max, self.min, self.R

    """Estimación del número de intervalos""" 
    def estima_numero_intervalos(self, df):
        # Número de muestras M
        self.M = df.size
        self.K = round(1 + 3.322 * math.log10(M) )   
        return self.K

    """Estimación del Tamaño de los intervalos"""    
    def estima_tamaño_intervalos(self, df):
        self.lim_inf = df.min()
        self.lim_sup = df.max()
        """Tamaño de los intervalos""" 
        self.C = math.ceil( self.R/self.K)
        return self.lim_inf, self. lim_sup, self.C

    def crea_intervalos(self, df):
        intervalos = pd.interval_range( start = self.min, end = self.max, freq = self.C,  name="Intervalo", closed="left")

        self.df_clases = pd.DataFrame(index=intervalos)
        self.df_clases["Fi"] = pd.cut(df , bins= self.df_clases.index).value_counts()
        # Media de cada intervalo del índice
        self.df_clases["Marca"]  = self.df_clases.index.mid

        self.df_clases["LimInf"] = self.df_clases.index.left
        self.df_clases["LimSup"] = self.df_clases.index.right
        return self.df_clases    
 
    def imprime():
        print ("\nNúmero de muestras M :\n", self.M)
        print ("\nMáximo valor", self.max)
        print ("\nMínimo valor",self. min) 
        print ("\nRecorrido de las variables R :", self.R)
        print ("\nNúmero óptimo de intervalos K:", self.K)
        print ("\nTamaño de los intervalos C:", self.C)
        print (self.df_clases)
        
        
tabla1 = ConstruyeIntervalos() 
#tabla1.calcula_numero_muestras(ventas)
#tabla1.calcula_recorrido (ventas)
tabla1.estima_numero_intervalos(ventas)

#tabla1.crea_intervalos(ventas) 
#tabla1.imprime()
```

¿Es correcto que ésto pueda ser tratado como una clase?.

Por otro lado, las dos últimas llamadas del objeto "tabla1" a los métodos "crea_intervalos()" e "imprime(), me dan error. Agradeceré aclaraciones para superar este error y sugerencias para mejorar ésta clase.

Siguiendo las sugerencias aprotadas, he corregido el código, quedando en este momento como sigue:

```
class ConstruyeIntervalos:
    def __init(self, df):
        self.df = df

    """Número de muestras"""
    def calcula_numero_muestras(self, df):
        """Número de muestras"""
        self.M = df.size
        return self.M

    """Recorrido de la variable""" 
    def calcula_recorrido (self, df):
        # Variables máxima y mínima
        self.max = df.values.max() 
        self.min = df.values.min()   
        self.R =  (self.max  - self.min ) 
        return self.max, self.min, self.R

    """Estimación del número de intervalos""" 
    def estima_numero_intervalos(self, df):
        # Número de muestras M
        self.M = df.size
        self.K = round(1 + 3.322 * math.log10(self.M) )   
        return self.K

    """Estimación del Tamaño de los intervalos"""    
    def estima_tamaño_intervalos(self, df):
        self.lim_inf = df.min()
        self.lim_sup = df.max()
        """Tamaño de los intervalos""" 
        self.C = math.ceil( self.R/self.K)
        return self.lim_inf, self.lim_sup, self.C

    def crea_intervalos(self, df):
        intervalos = pd.interval_range( start = self.min, end = self.max, freq = self.C,  name="Intervalo", closed="left")

        df_clases = pd.DataFrame(index=intervalos)
        df_clases["Fi"] = pd.cut(df , bins= df_clases.index).value_counts()
        # Media de cada intervalo del índice
        df_clases["Marca"]  = df_clases.index.mid

        df_clases["LimInf"] = df_clases.index.left

        #Lo instancio como variable de clase al final.
        self.df_clases["LimSup"] = df_clases.index.right
        return self.df_clases   
 
    def imprime(self):
        print ("\nNúmero de muestras M :\n", self.M)
        print ("\nMáximo valor", self.max)
        print ("\nMínimo valor",self.min) 
        print ("\nRecorrido de las variables R :", self.R)
        print ("\nNúmero óptimo de intervalos K:", self.K)
        print ("\nTamaño de los intervalos C:", self.C)
        print (self.df_clases)
        
        
tabla1 = ConstruyeIntervalos() 
tabla1.calcula_numero_muestras(ventas)
tabla1.calcula_recorrido (ventas)
tabla1.estima_numero_intervalos(ventas)
tabla1.estima_tamaño_intervalos(ventas)
tabla1.crea_intervalos(ventas) 
tabla1.imprime()
```

En este momento me devuelve el error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-44bec70c0d10> in <module>
     61 tabla1.estima_numero_intervalos(ventas)
     62 tabla1.estima_tamaño_intervalos(ventas)
---> 63 tabla1.crea_intervalos(ventas)
     64 tabla1.imprime()

<ipython-input-15-44bec70c0d10> in crea_intervalos(self, df)
     36 
     37         df_clases = pd.DataFrame(index=intervalos)
---> 38         df_clases["Fi"] = pd.cut(df , bins= df_clases.index).value_counts()
     39         # Media de cada intervalo del índice
     40         df_clases["Marca"]  = df_clases.index.mid

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py in cut(x, bins, right, labels, retbins, precision, include_lowest, duplicates)
    204 
    205     original = x
--> 206     x = _preprocess_for_cut(x)
    207     x, dtype = _coerce_to_type(x)
    208 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py in _preprocess_for_cut(x)
    553         x = np.asarray(x)
    554     if x.ndim != 1:
--> 555         raise ValueError("Input array must be 1 dimensional")
    556 
    557     return x

ValueError: Input array must be 1 dimensional
```

Comment: Por favor puedes agregar la traza de error que te da, para que podamos ayudarte!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Primera pregunta

> ¿Es correcto que ésto pueda ser tratado como una clase?.

Por supuesto que sí. Estás encapsulando distintas funciones, creando métodos que tienen **un proposito conjunto.** Te permite tenerlo todo en conjunto y **poder consultarlo cuando sea necesario**. **Reusarlo** varias veces, incluso podrías hacer **herencia de clases** ya que las operaciones de los intervalos se usan bastante en estadística.

De hecho en Python estás usando clases, constantemente. Si no lo crees, prueba a ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
help(int)
```

y su comienzo es así:

```
Help on class int in module builtins:

class int(object)
 |  int([x]) -> integer
 |  int(x, base=10) -> integer
 |  
 |  Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
```

Y si pruebas con `float`, `type`, `string`. Obtendrás que todos son clases, cada vez que creas un número, un float, un string, estás instanciando una clase. (si no lo crees puedes probar a usar `help(123)` por ejemplo.

## Error

El error que me da con tu código es el siguiente:

```
     42         # Número de muestras M
     43         self.M = df.size
---> 44         self.K = round(1 + 3.322 * math.log10(M) )
     45         return self.K
     46     """Estimación del Tamaño de los intervalos"""

NameError: name 'M' is not defined
```

Cuando utilizas el `self.` con una variable. La conviertes en una **instancia de la clase**, lo que significa que esa variable, no pertenece a la función, si no que **pertenece a la clase**, por lo tanto si quieres acceder a ella, debes acceder a tavés de la clase.

Como has definido **M** como una instancia de clase, utilizando `self.M`. Ya siempre tendrás que usar la clase para acceder a dicha variables, es decir siempre tendrás que usar `self.M`. Por ello debes de redefinir la función `estima_numero_intervalos()`. Esta función quedaría así:

```
  def estima_numero_intervalos(self, df):
        # Número de muestras M
        self.M = df.size #Has definido M como una instancia de clase.

        #Si llamas aquí a M sin usar el self. te dará un error puesto que en esta función no existe ningúna variable M definida.
        self.K = round(1 + 3.322 * math.log10(self.M)) 
        return self.K
```

### Advertencia

Dicho esto, por motivos de velocidad, y entendimiento de código, se deben usar la instanciación de variables (`self.`) solo cuando sea necesario:

- Velocidad: cada vez que tienes que acceder a una variable instanciada dentro de la función Python internamente tiene que salir del **scope** de la función y retornar el valor dentro del scope. Esto conlleva un delay de tiempo considerable, muchas veces mayor que el hacer el cálculo dentro de la función.
- Entendimiento de código: si declaras una variable de clase como instancia de dicha clase (es decir, usas `self.`) lo que le das a entender a otros programadores, es que esa variables es importante dentro de la clase, y va a ser usada o retornada más veces. Si defines todas las variables con `self.` se hace lioso saber cuando una variable fue creada por primera vez, los motivos y de donde viene (además de que es bastante pesado escribir self).

Por último indicarte que puedes definir una variable dentro de un método (función de clase), y convertirla al final en una instancia de clase, por ejemplo tu método `crea_intervalos()` podría quedar así:

```
def crea_intervalos(self, df):
    intervalos = pd.interval_range( start = self.min, end = self.max, freq = self.C,  name="Intervalo", closed="left")

    df_clases = pd.DataFrame(index=intervalos)
    df_clases["Fi"] = pd.cut(df , bins= df_clases.index).value_counts()
    # Media de cada intervalo del índice
    df_clases["Marca"]  = df_clases.index.mid

    df_clases["LimInf"] = df_clases.index.left
    
    #Lo instancio como variable de clase al final.
    self.df_clases["LimSup"] = df_clases.index.right
    return self.df_clases
```

Un ejercicio muy recomendable para seguir aprendiendo sería, coger esta clase que has creado, quedar solo las **variables de clase** necesarias para el funcionamiento del programa y para el programador que vaya a implementar dicha clase :) .

Comment: Muy útil y clara tu respuesta, Haré el  ejerciio que recomiendas. No obstante, con las correcciones me sigue dando el error: AttributeError: 'ConstruyeIntervalos' object has no attribute 'min'. Sin embargo, está definido como atributo de la calse, en la función calcula_recorrido.

Comment: Gracias. Por favor edita el código, porque estoy copiando y ejecutando el mismo código que tu tienes arriba, con el cambio que yo he hecho, y funciona perfectamente, por lo que tú código y el de la pregunta, deben ser distintos

Comment: He actualizado, respondiendo a tu primera pregunta @efueyo que se me había pasado por alto!

Comment: He corregido el constructor      "def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df"     y el método "crea_intervalos(self, df)", pero me sigue dando el error   "AttributeError: 'ConstruyeIntervalos' object has no attribute 'min' "

Comment: El problema era que, esa variable la he crado en el método calcula_recorrido(), así que tengo que llamar a este método antes. Voy probar  inicializando en el constructor todas las variables miembro de la calse que voy a usar.

Comment: He corregido el método "imprime", poniendo como primer parámetro self. "imprime(self)", pero me sigue dando el error  "ValueError: Input array must be 1 dimensional"

Comment: Como te he comentado, tienes que editar el código de tu pregunta. Yo estoy ejecutando el código y lo que estás usando arriba, y me funciona bien. Si no tengo tú código, no puedo ayudarte.... en la pregunta solo instancias la clase y ejecutas ```estima_numero_intervalos()``` y es correcto.

Comment: Parece que el error pueda estar relacionado con pd.cut() del método crea_intervalos(self.df). pd.cut()   segmenta los datos (y calcular las frecuencias absolutas). Cuando ejecuto esta función, en un script normal, sin clases, opera correctamente. Así que sigo sin entender éste error.

Comment: En este enlace "https://github.com/akitxu/Consultas-Programacion/blob/master/Crear_Intervalos_Clase.ipynb", se encuentra el notebook "Crear_Intervalos_Clase", script normal, sin clases, en el que la función equivalente al método que da el problema, funciona correctamente.